# Update time on timestamp column

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, sql-update

I'm trying to select with reference to one column changing its time in MySQL, but I don't know how.
How will I do it?

Example:

Time original: 2015-07-20 22:10:52
Updated: 2015-07-20 23:59:59

Comment: Don't look too far - this is a basic SQL statement. How would you update any column?

Comment: what is it, an insert or update stmt? the format would be like '2015-07-20 23:59:59' in single quotes

Comment: I'm so sorry, but I updated my question... I'm want to select changing column's time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`timestamp`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp) to join the current `timestamp`'s date with the time you want to set:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    mytimestamp = TIMESTAMP(DATE(mytimestamp), '23:59:59')
```

Answer (score 1):

To update with no reference to previous column value, it's no different from other columns. To update with it, and based on certain part (second, month, year, whatever), you can use [DATE_ADD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) or [DATE_SUB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) function. Any other function in the same page might be useful, too, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what type of column you have, your table can be modified with a standard [UPDATE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) statement.
You can also use the some special [time/date functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) to help you get the right format.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE mytable SET mytimestamp = mytimestamp::date + '23:59:59'::time;
```

it should work.